# What's the boldfaced dynamic type font that is used in many default app's collection view headers?

Tags: swift, iphone

I noticed a lot of the default apps that come on the iPhone which use collection views have a distinct style for the headers.  The font weight looks very bold and dynamically resizes.  Apps like Health, Photos, and Reminders all use it.  Here is an example [image]

It doesn't seem like it's any one of these text styles https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/textstyle.  What font is this exactly?  Also, is there a way I can go about inspecting what font is used in these default apps through simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the rounding at the ends of the strokes. (The bottoms of the "M" verticals are effectively semicircles.) It is thus presumably the bold system font with `.rounded` design:

[image]

So:

```
let f = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: n, weight: .bold)
    .fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded)!
let f2 = UIFont(descriptor: f, size: 0)
```

...where `n` is the desired size.

Comment: You're a legend.  Also I found this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-dynamic-type-with-a-custom-font which should help with scaling the font dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get exact font name from simulator.

I think the exact font is `Proxima Nova Soft Bold`
You can get the similar fonts with a captured image from several sites.

https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/

[image]